# access MongoDB without password outside LAN

Tags: mongodb

I have a pretty new installed MongoDB server and I want to access it from any computer outside the local area network it is on. All ports are forwarded and if I go onto `http://server-ip:28017` I can see it's web interface.

However, I still can't access my MongoDB server from my application. I don't want to turn on auth yet. Is there anything I've missed? Can't find anything in the docs.

Comment: What platform are you running? Is there a firewall in the path? 

What is the output of `sudo lsof -i :27017`?

Have you tried running `tcpdump` on the interface to see if traffic is hitting the interface on port 27017 or if it's being rejected through your host firewall?

Comment: Okay , your application layer is in which programming language or if so which driver you are using

Answer (score 0):

From application you have to connect to server-ip:27017  i.e -1000 of the web interface port

Comment: Thats what I've done. And it does not work :/. I even enabled auth mode and it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think mongod only listens on localhost by default. Check the arguments passed to mongod and try passing the --help option to see available parameters.

It might be a better idea, however, to set up and SSH tunnel and access it via proxy. It's safer, since you can bar all entry except from localhost. The tunnel command is simple:

```
ssh -N -L 12345:localhost:27017 user@remote
```

Then you would access the DB via localhost:12345 on you remote machine, i.e client.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, maybe a ssh tunnel is the only choice I've got.

Comment: It suffices if you don't want to keep it completely open to the internet, which is more often than not a bad idea.

Comment: By default, mongod will listen on all interfaces. The documentation for restricting that binding can be found [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Security+and+Authentication#SecurityandAuthentication-IPAddressBinding). You need to use `bind_ip` to bind to a specific IP address.